# How to get Kendo Grid Column Width

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

How do I display all Kendo grid column widths in a JavaScript alert?

I was trying this,

```
alert(JSON.stringify(grid.column));
```

but all I need is the column width.

Comment: Are the widths of your column specified in the grid configuration, or is the grid spacing them automatically, or both ?

Answer (score 5):

If your grid has the widths of each column specified in the grid configuration, you can get each column width on the column object of the grid.

If your grid is sizing columns automagically, you will need to access the underlying table, and use the `offsetWidth` on the table cell.

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var columnWidths = [];

$.each(grid.columns, function(i, col) {
    var colItem = {
        field: col.field,
        width: grid.table[0].rows[0].cells[i].offsetWidth
    };
    columnWidths.push(colItem);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(columnWidths));
```

See working sample at [Kendo Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ayoKu)